# Is it recommended to use GCE as a web server?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm new to the whole cloud concept. 
I have set up a Windows VM with GCE, remote desktopped into it, installed Apache HTTPD and set the firewall rules, turning this Google GCE into a web server. I intend to install Perl, which is my primary programming language and isn't supported in App Engine.
I am looking for an alternative to my current hosting solution for better uptime and availability, or at least a fall-back service.

Is it recommended to use GCE in this way or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Hosting/server recommendations/critique is off-topic.

Comment: I was looking for feedback on GCE, its recommended uses, and whether my particular use is recommended. Is that off-topic to questions about GCE?

Comment: yes, you're asking for opinions. those are EXPLICITLY off-topic

Comment: Understood. Where should I head for opinions on people familiar with GCE? https://cloud.google.com/support/#community explicitly lists stackoverflow as a community for GCE, which now seems not to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

GCE is a very general solution, you can use your VM for whatever purpose you want. In particular GCE is recommended for all workloads that do not fit in the rather strict limitations of App Engine.

Having said that, web hosting was probably the first and main use case for GCE when it was being implemented. On top of having a single VM serving your traffic you can trivially scale your solution up by using load balancers and/or autoscaling. On top of that you can use a managed DB if your web server needs storage, etc. So the answer is, yes, GCE is definitely designed to be used as a web server.